# Is it possible to select and edit the way the most recent post from a certain category is displayed on the page?

Tags: categories, loop, links

To explain... I have a loop that is getting the posts from a few different categories and for one category, I want to change the link that gets wrapped around the title.

For example:

I have 3 posts from the category "Events", I want the first 2 Events posts to link to their specific page and I want the latest, event #3, to link to a different page on the website (NOT the individual post's page like event #1 & 2).

So in the loop, I have something along the lines of:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink();?>"><h1>Title</h1></a>
```

And I want to change switch 'echo get_permalink' to '/events/signup' the latest Events posting at the same time, keeping 'echo get_permalink' for all the other category posts in the loop.

What's the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve the index of the post in the loop with `$wp_query->current_post`. From that, you can check with a simple if-statement:

```
/*Check if post index is 2 (you referred to the 3rd post, given indexing starts from 0, the 3rd post index would be 2 */
if ( $wp_query->current_post == 2 ) : 
   /* Do something */
else:
   /* Do something else */
endif;
```

Comment: I figured out this, however my account doesn't have enough reputation to post an answer... So unfortunately I cannot share here.